# PG::Error: ERROR: column reference "status" is ambiguous in active_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activeadmin

Using `rails 3.2` with `active_admin` and seeing `PG::Error: ERROR:  column reference "status" is ambiguous` when using a custom filter on `active_admin` in `Rents.rb`:

```
filter :travel_car_brand, as: :string
filter :travel_car_model, as: :string
```

The error points to:

```
: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "rents"."id") FROM "rents" LEFT OUTER JOIN "travels" ON "travels"."id" = "rents"."travel_id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "cars" ON "cars"."travel_id" = "travels"."id" WHERE ("cars"."brand" ILIKE '%mazda%') AND ("startDate" > '2014-08-04 10:15:14 +0200' and status = 'paid'):
```

it's interesting that the above has `status = 'paid'` since I'm not sure why its using that as a filter.

models

```
Rent.rb
belongs_to :travel

Travel.rb
has_one :car
```

and both rents table and travels table have a `status` attribute.

Comment: include `travels.status` `rents.rents`

Comment: hey @dude where and how should I include that? thanks

Comment: someone already answered it

Comment: "I'm not sure why its using that as a filter."

I suggest you find the line of code that is adding this filter and alter it to include the relevant model name.

Comment: i wonder why you are writing literals inside `""`

Comment: I'm going to guess the "" are because the person uses Navicat, which displays all tables and objects this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen [Lucas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25115265/385532) but if this is a rails app, the SQL should be generated by the application, not hardcoded. Therefore changing the SQL directly is not the solution.

Instead, I would suggest you find the code that is adding the "paid" filter and modify it to declare the relevant model name.

Somewhere you probably have a scope:

```
scope :paid, where(status: 'paid')
```

change that to (for example):

```
scope :paid, where("model.status = 'paid'")
```

Comment: While I hate applications that build sql with a burning passion it does seem to be the best solution ;)

Comment: it turned out the scopes where scope "Next departures" do |rents|
    rents.where("\"startDate\" > '#{Time.now}' and status = 'paid'")#.order("\"startDate\" ASC")
  end
  scope "Next arrivals" do |rents|
    rents.where("status = 'paid' AND \"endDate\" > '#{Time.now}'")#.order("\"endDate\" ASC")
  end and per your suggestion I changed status to rents.status

Answer (score 1):

You need to chose wich table you want your attribute to select, or use both

e.g.

```
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT "rents"."id")
FROM "rents"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "travels" ON "travels"."id" = "rents"."travel_id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "cars" ON "cars"."travel_id" = "travels"."id"
WHERE ("cars"."brand" ILIKE '%mazda%')
AND ("startDate" > '2014-08-04 10:15:14 +0200') 
AND rents.status = 'paid'
```

or if you require both:

```
SELECT
COUNT(DISTINCT "rents"."id")
FROM "rents"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "travels" ON "travels"."id" = "rents"."travel_id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "cars" ON "cars"."travel_id" = "travels"."id"
WHERE ("cars"."brand" ILIKE '%mazda%')
AND ("startDate" > '2014-08-04 10:15:14 +0200')
AND rents.status = 'paid'
AND travels.status = 'paid'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "status" column is ambiguous. Because SQL can't understand which one table's column you want. Rent.status or Travels.status that SQL can not understand.